# How to retrieve the underlier object from a binded Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ListRow?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, bindinglist

I am binding a `BingingList<T>` to an excel list object using the VSTO with Visual Studio 2010.

I want to be able to retrieve the object T given a excel ListRow object.  The only way I know how is to use ListRow.Range[1,1].ID.  It seems to return the index of T in the BindingList.  But the index is often not updated on time when the list is altered.

Is there a better way to achieve this?

thanks